# org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: can't redefine when using debezium connector and avro-maven-plugin

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, avro, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

The auto generated schema for table A:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Envelope",
  "namespace": "hello.A",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "before",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Value",
          "fields": [...],
          "connect.name": "hello.A.Value"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "after",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "Value"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "source",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Source",
        "namespace": "io.debezium.connector.mysql", // problem
        "fields": [...],
        "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "transaction",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "block",
          "namespace": "event", // problem
          "fields": [...],
          "connect.version": 1,
          "connect.name": "event.block"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ],
  "connect.version": 1,
  "connect.name": "hello.A.Envelope"
}
```

This alone works just fine. The problem is when there is multiple tables we listen cdc from that will have similar schema. For example:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Envelope",
  "namespace": "hello.B",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "before",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Value",
          "fields": [...],
          "connect.name": "hello.B.Value"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "after",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "Value"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "source",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Source",
        "namespace": "io.debezium.connector.mysql", // problem
        "fields": [...],
        "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "transaction",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "block",
          "namespace": "event", // problem
          "fields": [...],
          "connect.version": 1,
          "connect.name": "event.block"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ],
  "connect.version": 1,
  "connect.name": "hello.B.Envelope"
}
```

When generating java classes from these schemas via avro-maven-plugin, there will be a conflict.

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source
```

(the `event.block` will also cause conflict.)

Is there a way around this?

If I remove the namespace from `source` and `event.block` it works fine but I dont have the option to remove it?

I have tried to generate the java classes to different folders in avro-maven-plugin. But they will still have the same package name and will not compile.